# Checking value of child that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, pointers, dom, null

My html code contains a `<ul id="users"></ul>`, which is then populated dynamically with JS code

```
const li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${nameInput.value} : ${emailInput.value}`)
```

I added a button in the html code to delete all users in that `<ul>`,as such: `<button class="btn" id="del-user-list" onClick="deleteUserList()">Delete User List</button>`.

My deleteUserList function in the JS code looks like this:

```
function deleteUserList() {
  while (userList.firstChild != "") {
    userList.firstChild.remove();
  }
}
```

This works on the surface, however I realize that after the last child, my function will check once again for the value of a child that doesn't exist. I remember from studying C and playing with linked lists that you don't want to dereference a pointer that points to `null`.

Sure enough, when I look at the console I get
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove') at deleteUserList (main.js:31:25) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):29:77)`

Is this a problem and what can I do about it? I just started playing with Javascript and don't have a good sense of how those things work right now.

Comment: You should compare with `null`, not `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing `userList.firstChild` to an empty string, you should compare it against `null` or omit the comparison operator entirely:

```
while (userList.firstChild != null)
// or
while (userList.firstChild)
```

The latter one works because converting `null` to a boolean value returns `false`

`null != ''` will always be `true` because `userList.firstChild` will never be an empty string anyway. It will either be a DOM node or `null`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the details. Is it a problem to check for a child that doesn't exist? In other words are we accessing memory we're not supposed to once we've run out of children or if there aren't any in the first place?

Comment: You don't have to worry about this. JavaScript abstracts all memory management away. `firstChild` either has a DOM node as value or has `null` as value (`null` is an actual value in JavaScript (just like `42` is), I don't think it's comparable to a null pointer).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks again for explaining